# How can I turn a bad rule good?

Tags: sonarqube

Our SonarQube project is reporting violations across our codebase, because we have braces at the start of line instead of end of line.

Right or wrong, this is our accepted style. So how can we remove the end of line requirement and add a start of line requirement, and modify it a bit for else statements as

```
if()
{
} else {
}
```

Comment: You can disable the rule or lower the priority if you want. Very strange coding style.

Comment: It was just a quick example of a possible custom style ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's a Java Project, you may look for rules related to braces.
To see all java related rules dealing with braces, use:

```
https://yoursonarhost/coding_rules#languages=java|q=braces
```

From your example, [squid:LeftCurlyBraceStartLineCheck](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/coding_rules?open=squid%3ALeftCurlyBraceStartLineCheck&rule_key=squid%3ALeftCurlyBraceStartLineCheck) seems the wright rule.
Also possible to search with filter on specific Quality Profile, f.e.:

```
https://yoursonarhost/coding_rules#qprofile=java-sonar-way-74224|activation=true|q=braces
```

Then deactivate the rule that doesn't work for you or change it's severity. If no appropriate rule exists you may roll your own, based on those other brace rules, see sources:
[Sonarsource Java Analyzer sources](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/tree/master/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks)